# Display data after user input form (mysql-nodejs)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I have a page where there is a form, in which user will fill inputs. Then, I redirect to another page in which depending on the user's choices some data will be displayed (the data will come from a mysql database). This is my code: 
**index.js** (here are my routes)

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

// Controllers
const airTicketsController = require('../controllers/airTicketsController');

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('home', { title: 'Express' });
});

// Air tickets page
router.get('/air_tickets', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('air_tickets', { title: 'Air tickets' });
});

router.post('/form-submit', airTicketsController.airForm);
router.get('/air_ticketsSelect', airTicketsController.displayFlights);

module.exports = router;
```

**airTicketsController.js** (a controller where mysql queries will be executed)

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

// DB connection
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'myuser',
    password: 'mypassword',
    database: 'mydatabase'
});

connection.connect(function(error) {
    if (!!error) console.log(error);
    else console.log('CONGRATS! Database Connected! (airTicketsController)');
});

var variable1, variable2;

exports.airForm= (req, res) => {
    variable1 = req.body.from_destination;
    variable2 = req.body.to_destination
    res.redirect('/air_ticketsSelect');
}

exports.displayFlights= (req, res) => {
    variable1 = req.body.from_destination;
    variable2 = req.body.to_destination
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM flight WHERE from_destination=? AND to_destination=?", [variable1, variable2], function(err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.render('air_ticketsSelect', {
            title: 'flightdata',
            data: results
        });
    });
}
```

**air_tickets.ejs** (the page for the form)

```
<form id="form-submit" method="post" action="form-submit">
                            <div class="container" id="air-form-container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="from_destination">From: </label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="from_destination" class="form-control" placeholder="City or airport">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="to_destination">To: </label>
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="text" name="to_destination" class="form-control" placeholder="City or airport">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-btn">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit-btn">Search flights 
                                            <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
```

**air_ticketsSelect.ejs** (the page for displaying the data)

```
<table class="table table-dark table-striped">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>Airline</th>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>To</th>
                                <th>Depart date</th>
                                <th>Arrival date</th>
                                <th>Depart time</th>
                                <th>Arrival time</th>
                                <th>Price</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <% data.forEach(function(flight){ %>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.flight_id %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.airline %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.from_destination %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.to_destination %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.depart_date.toLocaleDateString('el-GR') %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.arrival_date.toLocaleDateString('el-GR') %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.depart_time %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.arrival_time %>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <%= flight.flight_price + ' €' %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <% }); %>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

In general, I think this is supposed to work. However, it doesn't display the data, only an empty table. If I do the query manually (e.g. SELECT * FROM flight WHERE from_destination = 'Paris' AND to_destination = 'London'), it will work correctly..

 When I console.log the query it says that: 
sql: 'SELECT * FROM flight WHERE from_destination=NULL AND to_destination=NULL',
values: [ undefined, undefined ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistakenly double defining variables.

In `exports.displayFlights` there is no need to again initialize the variables and **removing those two lines will solve your problem**.

Since, there is no `req.body` in `exports.displayFlights` your variables are getting initialized to `undefined`.